# How do I reset the ckeditor textArea

Tags: html, ckeditor

Let say I have an CKEditor

```
<div class="floor floor3">
    <dl class="">
        <dt>내용</dt>
        <dd>
            <%
                CKEditorConfig settings = new CKEditorConfig();
                settings.addConfigValue("height", 150);
                settings.addConfigValue("toolbar", "[[ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ],[ 'TextColor','BGColor' ],[ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ],[ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],[ 'Link','Unlink']]");
            %>
            <textarea cols="128" rows="10" id="brdConts" name="brdConts"></textarea>
            <ckeditor:replace replace="brdConts" config="<%=settings %>" basePath="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/ckeditor/"/>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.config.removeDialogTabs = "link:upload;link:advanced;image:Upload";
            </script>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

if I want to reset the TextArea after certain activity.
How should I reset it.

Comment: your code contains template tags, please add more information about your setup.

Comment: how do I find more information about my tag?

Comment: You want to reset textarea or the editor? What is certain activity? Could you provide more details?